Задать словарь, а потом использовать его как параметры вызываемой функции
Задача: вводить данные о разных видов доходов с клавиатуры и к введённым данным применить функцию. Проблема, как я понимаю, в самой последней строке, т.к. словарь выводится, но функция с ним не может ничего сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я неверно указываю?
def total_income_dict(**kwargs):
    """
    Функция для расчета общего дохода из нескольких источников.
    Ключи словаря: зарплата, доходы по вкладам, дивиденды, пособие."""
    total_income=0
    for value in kwargs.values():
        total_income+=value
    return total_income
keys = ('Зарплата', 'Вклады', 'Дивиденды','Пособия')
values = (int(input("Заработная плата составляет ")),int(input("Доходы по вкладам составляют ")),int(input("Дивиденды составляют ")),int(input("Пособия составляют ")))
dct1= dict(zip(keys,values))
print(dct1)
print(f"Совокупный доход составляет {total_income_dict(dct1)}")

В результате print(dct1) выполняется, словарь выходит, но далее
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-603119480ce8> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 dct1= dict(zip(keys,values))
     13 print(dct1)
---> 14 print(f"Совокупный доход составляет {total_income_dict(dct1)}")
     15 

TypeError: total_income_dict() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given


print(f"Совокупный доход составляет {total_income_dict(**dct1)}")

Большое спасибо!

Но вообще, не стоит так делать. если вам известен словарь, передавайте его в функцию как именованный аргумент.
